# Moving a class to a different name space

Tags: c++

I want to move a class to a different namespace but let the user uses the old namespace for a while (the user will know it was deprecated).

I had:

```
namespace vx {
    class vec3
    {
    public:
       vec3(double a, double b, double c);
       double length();
       vec3 operator+(const vec3& rhs) const;
    };
}
```

Now I have:

```
namespace vx
{
    class vec3
    {
    public:
        vec3(double a, double b, double c) : v(a, b, c) {}
        vec3(Math::vec3 iVec) : v(iVec) {}
        Math::vec3 operator=(const Math::vec3& iVec);
        operator Math::vec3() { return v; }
        operator Math::vec3() const { return v; }
    private:
        Math::vec3 v;
    };
}
namespace Math {
    class vec3
    {
    public:
        vec3(double a, double b, double c);
        double length();
    };
}
Math::vec3 operator+(const Math::vec3& lhs, const Math::vec3& rhs);
```

By converting unary `operator-(const vec3&) const` to binary `Math::operator-(const Math::vec3&, const Math::vec3&);`

I fixed alot of problem but now I still have problem with Math::vec::length()

In some old code I have

```
...
vx::vec3 v(1,2,3);
double l =  vec3.length(); // The implicit conversion doesn't work here!
```

How can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: You could add to `vx::vec3`: `double length() const { return v.length(); }`....

Comment: Does `Math::vec3` tend to be a fixed version of deprecated `vx::vec3` or are the 2 classes identical ?

Comment: We want to move the entire class vec3 to the new namespace. The deprecated class can be a stub to be able to compile old code without modification.

Answer (score 0):

Use namespace alias:

```
namespace vx = Math;
```

---

UPDATED:

If you can't replace whole `vx` namespace through namespace alias,
you can replace only `vx::vec3` class in it:

```
namespace Math {
class vec3 {
  // ...
};
}

namespace vx {
using Math::vec3;
}
```

---

UPDATED 2nd:

If you still have some problems regarding 'forward declaration',
How about this:

```
namespace Math {
class vec3 {
  // ...
};

// all other classes in vx namespace
using vx::vec1;
using vx::vec2;
}

#define vx Math
```

Comment: Unfortunately the namespace vx is already used and can't be an alias.

Comment: There is still some problem if the user has a forward declaration in his code (in one of his header file): 'namespace vx { class vec3; }'. He will get the following error: 'error conflicting declaration "using vec3 =" using vec3 = Math::vec3l" and 'error "class vx::vec3" has a previous declaration as "class vx::vec3"